# error expected declaration in family class

Tags: swift, xcode

i was making a family class when it popped up an error it was "expected declaration" i'm not sure what it means and how to debug it

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  familyClassSecond
//
//  Created by Dordor Zheng on 11/13/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Dordor Zheng. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class Person {

    var name : String!
    var age : String!
    var idNum : Int!

    init(name:String, age:String, idNum:Int){
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.idNum = idNum

    }

    func sayPerson() -> String{
    let S = "Hi i'm \(name) i am \(age) years old and my id is \(idNum)"
        print(S)
        return S

    }

}

class female : Person {
    var sex : String = "female"
    override func sayPerson() -> String {
        let S = "Hi i'm \(name) and i am \(age) years old"
        print(S)
        return S

    }
}


class male : Person {
    var sex : String = "male"
    override func sayPerson() -> String {
        let S = "Hi i'm \(name) and i am \(age) years old"
        print(S)
        return S

    }
}



class daughter: female {
    var mother : female!
    var father :  male!
    var sibbling : Array<Person>! = []


    init(me:female,father:male,mother:female,brother:male){
        super.init(name: me.name, age: me.age, idNum: me.idNum)
        self.father = father
        self.mother = mother

    }


    override func sayPerson() -> String {
        let S = "I'm \(name), i am \(age) years old my father is \(father.name) and my mother is \(mother.name)"
        print(S)
        return S

    }

    func appendSibbling(brother:Person){
    sibbling.append(brother)

    }



}



class brother: male {
    var mother : female!
    var father :  male!
    var sibbling : Array<Person>! = []


    init(me:male,father:male,mother:female,daughter:female){
        super.init(name: me.name, age: me.age, idNum: me.idNum)
        self.father = father
        self.mother = mother

    }


    override func sayPerson() -> String {
        let S = "I'm \(name), i am \(age) years old my father is \(father.name) and my mother is \(mother.name)"
        print(S)
        return S

    }

}







class father: male {
    var wife : female!
    var children : Array<Person>! = []


    init(me:male, wife:female,child:Person,brother:male){
        super.init(name: me.name, age: me.age, idNum: me.idNum)
        self.wife = wife
        self.children.append(child)
        self.children.append(brother)

    }



    if(children.count == 1 || children.count == 0){
    var choose = "child"
    }else{
    choose = "children"
    }


    override func sayPerson() -> String {
        let S = "I'm \(name), i am \(age) years old i have \(children.count) children and my wife is \(wife.name)"
        print(S)
        return S

    }

}


class mother: female {
    var husband : male!
    var children : Array<Person>! = []


    init(me:female, husband:male,child:Person,brother:male){
        super.init(name: me.name, age: me.age, idNum: me.idNum)
        self.husband = husband
        self.children.append(child)
        self.children.append(brother)

    }


    override func sayPerson() -> String {
        let S = "I'm \(name), i am \(age) years old i have \(children.count) children and my husband is \(husband.name)"
        print(S)
        return S

    }

}



class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        let one = female(name: "Dordor", age: "8", idNum: 388313)
        let two = male(name: "Tiger", age: "24", idNum: 773424)
        let three = male(name: "Chiwen", age: "48", idNum: 143303)
        let four = female(name: "Hongwen", age: "47", idNum: 243332)


        let child = daughter(me: one, father: three, mother: four, brother: two)
        let mom = mother(me: four, husband: three, child: one,brother:two)
        let dad = father(me: three, wife: four, child: one,brother: two)
        let bigB = brother(me: two, father: three, mother: four, daughter: one)

        child.sayPerson()
        mom.sayPerson()
        dad.sayPerson()
        bigB.sayPerson()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

do you have any ideas and the error is on the if
you can copy paste into your code cause i'm using swift 9.2(it's not beta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `choose` a *computed* property:

```
var choose : String {
    if children.count == 1 || children.count == 0 {
        return "child"
    } else {
        return "children"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pick between two options that you have

- Convert choose to a lazy variable:

  lazy var choose: String = {
        if(self.children.count == 1 || self.children.count == 0){
           return "child"
        } else {
           return "children"
        }
     }()
- Make choose a function:

  func choose() -> String {
        if(self.children.count == 1 || self.children.count == 0){
           return "child"
        }else{
           return "children"
        }
     }